# Spring integration test - AutoWiring classes without RunWith annotation (AWS localstack)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration, localstack

I am trying to write an integration test. I want to use local stack to spin up a docker container mocking AWS services.

This code will spin up the docker container and but will not autowire the classes from my spring application.

```
@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb","sns"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestApplication.class})
public class FlowTest {
    @Autowired
    private PublisherFactory publisherFactory;

    @Test
    public void publishMessage() {
        // publisherFactory is null here 
        Publisher publisher = publisherFactory.getInstance("test-event");
    }
}
```

This code will Autowire the classes from my application but does not start the Docker container

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb","sns"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestApplication.class})
public class FlowTest {
    @Autowired
    private PublisherFactory publisherFactory;

    @Test
    public void publishMessage() {
        //publisher not null here but Docker container not running
        Publisher publisher = publisherFactory.getInstance("test-event");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using Junit 4 you can only use a single `@RunWith`.

This will cause you issues as you can't run both `LocalstackTestRunner` and `SpringRunner`.

There are a few ways you can over come this:

The minimal amount of change is to use Junit 4 [class rules](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ClassRule.html)

So your test could be changed to look like the following

```
@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb","sns"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestApplication.class)
public class LocalstackJunit4Test {

  @ClassRule
  public static final SpringClassRule springClassRule = new SpringClassRule();

  @Rule
  public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

  @Autowired
  private PublisherFactory publisherFactory;

  @Test
  public void publishMessage() {
     Publisher publisher = publisherFactory.getInstance("test-event");
  }

}
```

This set-up will set-up the docker containers and Spring application.

---

Junit 5 example

Ensure the test import is `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and the following

```
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = {"dynamodb","sns"})
@ExtendWith(LocalstackDockerExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestApplication.class)
class LocalstackJunit5Test {


  @Autowired
  private PublisherFactory publisherFactory;

  @Test
  void publishMessage() {
     Publisher publisher = publisherFactory.getInstance("test-event");
  }

}
```

---

Alternative options are:

You could use the Localstack class rules via test containers see documentation [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/localstack/).

or

You can use Junit 5 which allows you to use [extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) which again can use [test containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/) and [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.html).

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I have got the extendsWith annotation I would like to use that approach if it is the cleanest solution although when i use @ExtendWith(LocalstackDockerExtension.class)
The docker container still does not spin up. Any ideas?

Comment: I have added an update for the JUnit 5 ExtendWith which will spin up docker and Spring.